# Reduce complexity of a maximum repeated element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I got a list of exercise to do before my exams, they are not graded that's why I did not mark them as homework.

The algorithm take an array of numbers

Given this algorithm:

```
         Algo-X(A)
                i=1 
                j=1  
                m=0 
                c=0
                while i ≤ |A|
                    if A[i] == A[j]
                        c=c+1 
                    j=j+1
                    if j > |A|
                        if c > m
                           m=c 
                        c=0
                        i=i+1
                        j=i 
                return m
```

Question 1: Analyze the complexity of Algo-X.

Question 2: Write an algorithm that does exactly the same thing as Algo-X but with a strictly better
asymptotic time complexity.

Now, the time complexity of this is O(n^2) right?

The algorithm itself from what I understood search inside an array and return number of the maximum repeated number inside an array.

How can I reduce the complexity?

I can not assume that there is a number that is N/2 times present.

Thanks guys

Comment: Are you sure the line `c=c+1 j=j+1` is correct?

Comment: Can you use a hashmap? In this case, O(n) should be possible.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!
I have to work only with arrays, but even with hash map if all the number are different, (1,2,3,4,5) the complexity will be the same. He asked for a strictly better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, the time complexity of this is O(n^2) right?

Yes, you are right. `j` will iterate over all elements from `i` to `|A|` for every `i` from `1` to `|A|`.

∑<sub>i = 1..|A|</sub>∑<sub>j = i..|A|</sub>(j) = O(|A|<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

> How can I reduce the complexity?

You can first sort the initial array. Then all equal numbers will occur sequentially. You just look for the longest group of equal elements.

```
sort(A)
m = 1
c = 1
i = 2
while i ≤ |A|
    if A[i] == A[i - 1]
        c = c + 1
    else 
        c = 1
    if c > m
        m = c
    i = i + 1
```

The time complexity will be O(n * log(n)) for sorting and O(n) for working with sorted array. The total time complexity will be O(n * log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easily solvable in linear time and linear space---e.g. by using a hashtable. Here's a pseudocode:

```
HashTable<Integer, Integer> H = new HashTable<Integer,Integer>();
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
    if (H.contains(A[i])) { H[A[i]] = 1; }
    else { H[A[i]] += 1; res = Math.max(H[A[i]], res); }
}

return res
```

It's also solvable in `O(n log n)` time (and even in `O(n)` time if the numbers in `A` are sufficiently similar) and `O(1)` space by sorting and then scanning the array.

```
sort(A)
i = j = 0;
res = 0;
while i < |A| do
    j = i+1
    while j < |A| && A[i] == A[j] do
        j = j+1
    done
    res = max(res, j-i+1)
    i = j
done
// Separately handle the case when |A|=1
if |A| = 1 then
    res  = 1
end
return res
```

Even better, if max difference of elements in `A` is of order `|A|`, you can sort `A` in linear time using [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (or some other [integer sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting)). Then the algorithm runs in linear time.

Comment: Corrected the algorithm, it was a problem of indentation. It is the first problem, but with has table if all the element are different is not the same complexity?

Comment: If you know that the table contains all distinct elements, then the answer is 1. In this case the problem doesn't make sense.